# Git flag to report status immediately on executing command?

Tags: git

It doesn't take much effort to type `git status` as a follow-up command to something like `git add .`, but I'm wondering if there's a flag that can be appended to the first command, e.g. `git add . -st[atus]` (that's obviously not a real flag, but you get the idea). It would be nice to get something more than a prompt after entering a command.

Comment: If you want to have the `git status` after every command you can change your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this kind of command-line option doesn't exists.

What about defining an alias? For example you can alias 'status' with 'st', this allows you to type `git st` instead of `git status`.

> git alias st status

If you're under a bash environment, you can also define a classical alias, for example `gst` for `git status`. Simply type in ~/.bash_aliases or similar config file

> alias gst='git status'

Comment: My main objective was to modify a command by appending a status flag to avoid a second entry, even if that second entry is only a couple of characters. It's not a make-or-break issue, I just assumed the flag already existed. I'll probably change my prompt, as Micha Wiedenmann suggested.